# Lower strings buzz after switching from 0.010" to 0.009" gauge, should I raise the saddles to fix it?

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

I replaced the strings on my low end Stagg electric guitar. I changed from 0.010" to 0.009" to make it a little more comfortable to play. After replacing the strings I notice the A and low E string buzz a lot more against the frets. I assume this is because of the lower tension these sets need to be in tune, compared to the old set, bending the neck a little less forward. I think this results in lower action leading to the buzzing strings. Is this assumption likely correct?

The fix I'm thinking of is raising the saddles on these strings. If any pictures are helpful, just let me know which specific details to capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising the saddles is one solution but you could try loosening the truss rod 1/4 to 1/2 turn to add a little more relief to the neck to compensate for the lighter gauge strings and lower tension. If you notice the action now is slightly lower than before this is worth a try before the raising the saddles. Check the relief by holding the low E string at the first fret and also at the fret where the neck meets the body. If there is very little or no gap between the string and the frets in the center then loosening the truss rod is the way to go. You can always return it to its original adjustment, just keep track of how much you turned it.

Comment: Loosened the truss rod and it helped a lot. I'm not sure how much I turned it in total, but most (if not all) of the buzzing is gone. I'll give it a few more days to settle.
Turns out I don't have the right sized tools to raise the saddles, but it might not be needed after all.

Comment: Most saddles are adjusted with either a very small flathead screwdriver or a hex key. The pocket knife style hex sets usually have one that’s small enough for the saddles, you just need to know if it’s imperial or metric. Actually it’s handy to have one of each!

Answer (score 0):

Man, you went from a thicker string gauge to a thinner gauge, did you verify the lower strings size to the ones you used to have on it, making sure that the string size went down between the string sets, usually you would go to a lighter gauge string, buzzing and ringing go away.  You may have to have your truss rod adjusted, because of the string gauge change.  I recommend you take the guitar to your local music store, have the tech inspect it, and give his diagnosis of the problem, could be as simple as a truss rod adjustment.  Good luck1